# how to remove all script tags in a html content with CsQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css-selectors, csquery

i am using CsQuery library for crawling. Code is like this.

```
 var dom = CQ.CreateDocument(htmlContent);
resultText= dom[cssSelector].Text();
```

I don't want script tags in `resultText` for example this part `<script> somethings </script>`

I tried this `dom[cssSelector].Not("script").Text();` . But is not working.

How can i delete all script values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. This code removes all scripts.

```
dom = dom["body script"].Remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

The library hasn't been updated in over three years, so it is possible that it no longer works.

Looking at the given documentation, you can try using:

```
CQ script = dom["script"];
script.remove();
```

This will remove all script tags